# Peewee messing up key names with strange parenthesis

Tags: python, orm, peewee

How come with a query like this:

```
latest_dates = EquityModel.select(EquityModel.symbol, fn.MAX(EquityModel.date)).where(EquityModel.symbol << symbols).group_by(EquityModel.symbol)
    for latest_date in latest_dates.dicts():
        print("{:s} - {:d}".format(str(latest_date['date']), latest_date['symbol']))
```

I get a `KeyError` with `'date'` but not with `'symbol'`, given that both are present in `EquityModel`?

If I analyse `latest_date` in the debugger, it looks like this:

```
{'date")': datetime.datetime(something), 'symbol': 3}
```

If I try to access `latest_dates['date")']` it works!

What exactly is going on here? Why `date` becomes `date")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's going on, you can explicitly assign an alias using: `fn.MAX(EquityModel.date).alias('date')`.

Is EquityModel.date a computed field, or is it a normal column?

Comment: Thanks for your help! 'date' is a simple DateTimeField(). I will try to assign an alias and see if ti works.

Comment: This fixed it, still very strange behavior, please let me know if I can help. Cheers!

Comment: Are you using an old version of sqlite?